# Proxy port without changing URL in apache

Tags: apache, proxy, apache2, mod-proxy

is there a way to proxy URL to another port in apache?
For example I would like to (reverse) proxy URL:

```
http://*.localhost/engine.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling
```

from port 80 to port 8080 without changing url:

```
http://*.localhost:8080/engine.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `*.localhost` (port 80) vhost, add:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/engine\.io/$ http://%1:8080/engine.io/?%{QUERY_STRING} [L,P]
```

Comment: @kamylko You can't use a wildcard with `ServerName`, you need `ServerAlias`. See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html

Comment: I am affraid that these rewrite conditions somehow interfering with zend project .htaccess or something.